# Parcel build process and creating files

Tags: bundle, parceljs

I'm using parcel for a vanilla JS project and want to intercept the build process to generate path-based routes kind of like nuxt, gatsby, next etc...

For that I need to intercept the build process, create the routes in a file and stuff, but I tried to follow Parcel Bundler API to no success, besides, I don't know if I'm palcing the file correctly, right know I'm using an index.js as a sibling to package.json and the scripts run parcel index.js.

Could anyone help me figure this out? Thanks.